# Firebase Callable Function works on one project, throws Error on the other

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

I get `ERROR Error: internal` on my Ionic-Angular app (in the **Chrome DevTool**) after calling a basic callable Firebase cloud function. My app is running locally using the `ionic serve` command.

- The cloud function is as follows:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions
  .region("europe-west2")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
    return "Hello from Firebase!";
  });
```

- I call the function from my app in the following way:

```
this.AngularFireFunctions
        .httpsCallable("helloWorld")({})
        .toPromise()
        .then((r) => console.log(r));
```

- The full error that appears in my Chrome DevTool log is as follows:

```
app.component.ts:46 Error: internal
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (index.cjs.js:60)
    at _errorForResponse (index.cjs.js:155)
    at Service.<anonymous> (index.cjs.js:560)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:368)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:130)
    at zone-evergreen.js:1272
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:402)
```

To pinpoint the issue, I tried running the same thing on this other Ionic-Angular project of mine. I did so in exactly the same way (same code as above), in exactly the same location (`app.component.ts`), with the same version of AngularFire (`^6.0.2`), and ran in the same way (using `ionic serve`) **but it ended up working on that second project!**

### Firebase logs comparison

- **No logs** appear on Firebase when I call the function from the **first project** (a.k.a. when I get the error).
- I get **logs of normal functioning** when called from the **second project** (a.k.a. when it is successful). There are two, which are as follows: `Hello logs! {"structuredData":true}`, and `Function execution took 4 ms, finished with status code: 200` .

I tried going through the same process for **another cloud function**, and regardless of the function I call, the **same thing happens**: I get error internal on that first project, and the function is called successfully on that second project.

I'm assuming that means the error can't be server-side, nor in the way I make the call, but then what is it? I'm clueless as where to even look now! What else comes into play and could cause this issue? Could something be interfering with the process? Any help, hints or advises would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

My co-worker pulled my version of the first project from GitHub, and the cloud function ran correctly without throwing `Error: Internal`! Could my project be corrupted or something?

Comment: Where does [Error: Internal] show up? If this is in the logs then check what was happening before it and also check the same in the location where it worked.

Comment: If by logs you mean the Chrome DevTool's logs, then exactly. I'll modify my post to show you what the whole error says, but it seems to tell me nothing about the error's nature. It's a super generic error which I believe is thrown by Firebase (indeed, you get exactly the same error if there is an unhandled error in your cloud function code)

Comment: Is there any detail on Firebase log (not Chrome Dev tools)? Because you mentioned a small change on that function which were working on another project, right?

Comment: No, the function I call from both projects is exactly the same! No logs appear on Firebase when I call the function from the first project (a.k.a. when I get the error). I get logs of normal functioning when called from the second project (a.k.a. when it is successful): one is `Function execution took 4 ms, finished with status code: 200`, the other is `Hello logs! {"structuredData":true}`.

Comment: Can you check that the localhost Node server is not running? I am wondering if this is why you are getting this error message.

Comment: I'm not sure this is why because I've never used a localhost Node server before! I run both of my projects locally using `ionic serve`, and when the error has occurred on one but not the other, I was running both at the same time! I've also tried exchanging their localhosts (8100 <--> 8101) just in case that would change anything, and nothing changes.

Comment: I just changed from tslint to eslint quite recently, could it have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the end of this problem!

I had to delete both my `/node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file
(`/dist` would also be a good idea, but I didn't have one), and then run `npm install` to reinstall all dependencies and rebuild the `package-lock.json` folder.

What I would do in the past was **only** delete the `/node_modules` folder, which, as I understand it now, left `package-lock.json` untouched and installing older versions of dependencies, creating conflicts and hence this `ERROR: internal`.